# PDE question that hard to see second first integral

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, cauchy-problem

> Solve the IVP. $x\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y} = z- x^2-y^2, \; z\vert_{y=-2} = x-x^2 $

*$\underline{\text{My Attempt:}}$*

I first wrote Characteristic Equation for the correpsonding PDE. Here is the Characteristic equation:

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{dx}}{x}=\dfrac{\mathrm{dy}}{y}=\dfrac{\mathrm{dz}}{z-x^2-y^2}$$

And clearly the first, first integral is:

$$\dfrac{x}{y}=\phi_1(x,y,z)$$

But I couldn't find the second first integral. Could someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is it $dy/y$, or is there a typo in the original equation?

Comment: I corrected it. There was a typo

Comment: Alright. I guess I'm not familiar with the method you have in mind. The method I have learned to analyze this is to identify a characteristic as satisfying $\frac{dx}{dt}=x,\frac{dy}{dt}=y$ and then note that along a characteristic you have $\frac{dz}{dt}=z-x^2-y^2$. Pin down when the characteristics hit the boundary and then you just turn the crank with some ODEs to get implicit solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{z-x^2-y^2}=\frac{2x\,dx+2y\,dy+dz}{2x^2+2y^2+(z-x^2-y^2)} = \frac{d(x^2+y^2+z)}{x^2+y^2+z}$$

$$\ln|x|=\ln|x^2+y^2+z|+\text{constant}$$
A second integral :
$$\frac{x^2+y^2+z}{x}=\phi_2$$
I suppose that you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you define $u(x,y) = z(x,y)+x^2+y^2$ the equation reduces to $xu_x+yu_y=u$, which is easier to analyse.

If $z=u-x^2-y^2$, then $xz_x +yz_y=xu_x-2x^2+yu_y-2y^2$, but $z-x^2-y^2=u-2x^2-2y^2$, giving the required equation.

Comment: You mean $u=z-x^2-y^2$ right?

Comment: I didn't mean that: see expanded answer.